# How to delete a specific folder in a GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, repo

I m a beginner in open source and I was committed a wrong file in my GitHub repository, I just want to just delete it and here is a picture and the link..... [Screenshot of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf7hG.png)

[Here is the problem](https://github.com/StarKnightt/Hacker-Rank-Questions/commit/b636e5a3c011fb971869c9324d143e2286e93a65) I just want to delete in and nothing more.

[Link to my repository](https://github.com/StarKnightt/Hacker-Rank-Questions)

Comment: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/github-delete-folder

Comment: Git doesn't do "folders". The problem is DevCard.yml.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this step

```
git rm -r --cached FolderName 
git commit -m "Removed folder from repository" 
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have checked out the repo in your workstation.

Steps:

1. Go to the folder in your workstation
2. Select & delete the folder/file (if its hidden file then make sure its visible)
3. git commit & git push
4. Done